# Remember network drive password on XP and Vista

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Map Network Drive with Password](https://superuser.com/questions/23646/map-network-drive-with-password)

When I access a mapped network drive, I'm asked to provide the login/password information for the server even though I have the remember password option checked.

How can I force Windows XP and Vista remember the network password?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/23646/map-network-drive-with-password

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to create a batch file of Net Use commands and run it on boot. I don't know of a way to make it remember the password otherwise.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true