# How to not require username/password for XP network share?

Tags: windows-xp, security, network-shares

When I connect to a network share in XP I am being asked for a username/password.  How can I prevent this happening. Usually this is not required.

Comment: It was already posted before:
http://superuser.com/questions/44658/remember-network-drive-password-on-xp-and-vista

Comment: @Miroco: that is not the same question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn on simple file sharing in My Computer | Tools | Folder Options | View
2. Uninstall and then reinstall "File and Printer Sharing For Microsoft Networks" service for network connection in Control Panel | Network Connections

Answer (score 0):

You want to Disable a Password Protected Sharing with XP ?
try this, meybe this steap can help you;

1.Click on the "Start" button, then select "Control Panel."

2.Click on "Network and Sharing Center" from the Control Panel.

3.Click on the down arrow next to "Password Protected Sharing."

4.Check the bubble next to "Turn Off Password Protected Sharing."

5.Click "Apply," and exit.

Tips & Warnings;
When you disable password-protected sharing, a computer sharing the folder does not require a user account or password. Any computer on your network can access the files and folders you set to share.

Comment: Are you sure this applies to XP?  The "Network and Sharing Center" is in Win 7, not in XP.